# How to say in correct tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

I want to say in English about some fact in the past, but it has an impact the present:

> I have **starting** going to the gym *last week*? (I still go there)

or

> I have **started** going to the gym *last week*? (I still go there)

What about that I want to say about the same action, but that action began much earlier:

> I have **starting** going to the gym *two years ago*? (I still go there)

or

> I have **started** going to the gym *two years ago*? (I still go there)

Answer (score 3):

The auxiliary *have* is always followed by a past participle, never any other form, so *I have starting* is never grammatical.

> I have started going to the gym.

is grammatical, and completely natural, if you started recently, and are still continuing.

For me, I would not use the present perfect with a specified time, so I would not say *I have started going to the gym last week*, but rather

> I started going to gym last week.

I would not count the form with *have started* as ungrammatical, but as less idiomatic.

If you are talking about two years ago, *I have started going to the gym* is disctinctly odd. If I've just met somebody I haven't seen for ten years, I could say *I've started going to the gym* for any time in those ten years, as long as I'm still going there; but in any other context it wouldn't fit.

Comment: Of course, one would never say: I have started going to the gym last week. Why not just say it is ungrammatical? I think the only people who say that kind of thing are French and Spanish speakers. The French translate passé composé incorrectly as present perfect and in Spanish the equivalent to the present perfect could be grammatical.

Comment: Hi thank You for response. So in the end: If I say : I started going to gym last week it could mens I’m still going, or not? Sorry 4my English...  Where I live in Poland we have, a problem with a perfect tenses...

Comment: @KamilJ: Yes, _I started going to the gym last week_ probably (but not definitely) means that you are still going; but I say "probably" only because "last week" is recent. _I started going to the gym last year_ is completely open as to whether or not you are still going.